# How to disable virtual IP on centOS

Tags: ip, centos6, nic

I have 5 Centos machines and 2 of them have virtual IP enable on it. This is causing problem for some of the application specifically MapR.

Here i need to disable virtual IP address.

I have a temprory solution which is below command:

```
sudo ifconfig virbr0 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0 down
```

It works for a session but when i reboot the system it automatically get up i cannot find any ifcfg-virbr0  entry in network-script how can i disable it on startup.

Comment: do you have libvirt on the system?

Comment: @ALex_hha No we don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to disable virbr0.

On MapR, you may want to investigate MAPR_SUBNETS. From the [documentation for MapR 5.2](http://maprdocs.mapr.com/home/AdministratorGuide/Designating-Subnets-for-MapR.html?hl=mapr_subnets):

> By default, MapR automatically uses all available network interface
>   cards (NICs) on each node in a network. However, in some scenarios you
>   might want MapR to use a restricted subnet of NICs. For example, if
>   you use multiple NICs of mixed speeds (such as 1GbE and 10GbE) on each
>   node, you might want to separate them into two subnets. That way, you
>   can use the faster NICs for MapR and the slower NICs for other
>   functions.

So in your case, MAPR_SUBNETS should be set to the subnet on the interfaces that you want MapR to use for its traffic (RPCs between nodes). MapR will then not consider interfaces not in the subnets in MAPR_SUBNETS for cluster communication.

HTH

--vince

Answer (score -1):

The `virbr0` is a 'dummy' device that accompanies actual `br0` bridge. So maybe what you want to do is to completely disable `br0`. Search the network scripts for `DEVICE=br0`. If not found, search the initialization scripts for `br0` maybe some manual cruft is to be discovered there.

The relevant documentation is at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Network_Configuration-Bridged_networking_with_libvirt.html

Comment: i created ifcfg-br0 script and set onboot=no but it dint worked.

Comment: virbr0 is not a dummy device, it is itself an actual bridge.